# Publishing Failure due to Polling for notification and IOExceptions - SDL 9.6

Tags: publishing, sdl-tridion, deployer, si4t, deployerservice

We faced few instance in last month where we published variety of components and pages in preview and live environment. We saw a series of failure. We almost pushed 2275 pages and component in the queue out of which 879 got failed. Almost all failure occurred due to “polling for notification for destination: has exceeded polling attempt for transaction: tcm x-xxxxx-xxxx”. Publishing failure was observed on both the target.

We verified deployer logs and found that log level set to info during the time of publishing. The other observation was, the failure was in continuation. Queue started collapsing and it recovered when we restart and clear the deployer.

Next day we set the deployer log level to debug(by updating si4t jar files) and tried to publish the pages. We almost publish 979 pages out of which 148 got failed. In this time reason behind the failure was “polling for notification for destination: has exceeded polling attempt for transaction: tcm x-xxxxx-xxxx”. This error occurred in two phases. On preparing deployment and committing deployment.

While verifying the deployer logs we only found IOEXception.

2023-xx-xx 07:55:29.xxx ERROR [deployer-combined-service,xxxxxxxx,development,live] 13 --- [t-dispatcher-13] org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer                : IOException occurred when talking to server at: xxxx/xxx/xxx
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: xxxx/xxx/xxx
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:695)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteById(SolrClient.java:868)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteById(SolrClient.java:827)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteById(SolrClient.java:842)
at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexDispatcher.removeFromSolr(SolrIndexDispatcher.java:249)
at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer.removeItemsFromSolr(SolrIndexer.java:434)
at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer.commit(SolrIndexer.java:263)
at com.tridion.storage.si4t.SearchIndexProcessor.triggerIndexing(SearchIndexProcessor.java:233)
at com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory.commitTransaction(JPASearchDAOFactory.java:191)
at ………..

We have verified event system logs as well as CM server logs. We didn’t find any triggering factor. We wanted to know the reason behind publishing failure. Was it happened due to polling issue or is IOExceptions responsible for publishing failure? If I wanted to fix these issues is there any workaround on this?

Your suggestions and inputs are valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Your Stack Trace gives a pretty clear context of the error:

- It happens in the SI4T (the open source Search Integration for Tridion) indexer
- When trying to remove items from Solr
- When communicating with Solr server xxx/xx/xx
- An IOException occurred

Unfortunately, "An IOException ocurred" is still rather general. Maybe there's another log entry which has more details about what kind of IOException? For example, is the Solr server completely unreachable?  Maybe the Solr logs can also provide more insight in what the problem is.